# django get POST data with a spaces inside

Tags: django, post

I need to get POST data with spaces in it.

I have folder with files in it.
Files can have different names, so the problem when I am working with files which contains spaces in their name, like "some long  name with spaces.txt"
This is html form, nothing special:

```
<form action="" method=post>
 {{ form }}
 <table border="1">
    <tr><td>File Name</td><td>upload</td></tr>
       {% for file in file_list %}
       <tr>
       <td>{{ file }}</td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="file" value={{ file }} /> <br /></td>
    </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</table>
<input name="" type="submit" value="Sent">
```

So while processing data from this form:

```
new_file = request.POST.getlist('file')
```

data processing, like moving, renaming and etc i am getting following error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'upload/some'
```

seems to me, it cuts everything after first word, how I can bypass this issue?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surround your value field with quotes and you should be fine. (Just tested this)

`<input type="checkbox" name="file" value={{ file }} />`

should be

`<input type="checkbox" name="file" value="{{ file }}" />`